# How to use ProcessBuilder API to sign a jar file programatically

Tags: java

We are developing a small Java Program which will sign the jar file. For Signing the Jar file using a jarsigner we are using a ProcessBuilder API for creating the command. But we are getting error while executing it.

Below given is the code snippet:

```
String command = "jarsigner -verbose -keystore "%KEYSTORE%" -digestalg SHA1 "%JAR FILE%" "%ALIAS%" -storepass "%PASSWORD%"

ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
Process p = processBuilder.start();
```

But while execution we are getting the IOException as response.

Then I also tried by creating the String array:
Below given is the code snippet:

String [] commands = new String[]{"jarsigner", "-verbose" , "-keystore ./sample/xyz.keystore" , "-digestalg SHA1 " , "./sample/xyz.jar" , "alias" , "password"};

ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
Process p = processBuilder.start();

Output: It is displaying the options provided by jarsigner , this is the behavior when the arguments provided are not correct. But if I am trying the same command from command prompt it is working properly.

Please help in executing the command using ProcessBuilder.

Comment: Hello , by putting the keystore and keystore values separate the command is working, but it is giving an response on Java 1.6 , it is working on Java 1.7 and above. But we need to make it work on 1.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per its [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#ProcessBuilder(java.lang.String...)) ProcessBuilder takes an array of Strings to specify the command. The first element is the program that will be executed, the rest are arguments.

Another reason why this isn't working is that ProcessBuilder does not replace environment variables (since it has no idea what they could look like on any given OS). Use [System.getenv()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv()) instead.

Which leaves the array looking like this:

```
String command[] = { "jarsigner", "-verbose", "-keystore", System.getenv("KEYSTORE"), ... }
```

To respond to your edit, your problem is that you need to separate "-keystore" and "./sample/.." into two array elements.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply. We tried even with the array , but no success.

Comment: Are you sure you did it correctly and understood the documentation? Please edit your question to include your full stack trace and everything you've tried so far (even the stuff you tried just now). Otherwise helping is really difficult and you won't get any good answers.

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer. I didn't understand what you meant with %KEYSTORE% until now (since you didn't explain it in your question), but I'm guessing it's supposed to be an environment variable on Windows in which case it won't work like you're doing it.

Comment: String [] commands = new String[]{"jarsigner", "-verbose" , "-keystore ./sample/xyz.keystore" , "-digestalg SHA1 " , "./sample/xyz.jar" , "alias" , "password"};
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
Process p = processBuilder.start();

Output: It is displaying the options provided by jarsigner , this is the behavior when the arguments provided are not correct. But if I am trying the same command from command prompt it is working properly.

Comment: You should really edit your question with this information. Just click on "edit" under the question.

Comment: I edited my answer to point out your mistake and removed my downvote on the question. For the future though: Always post everything you've tried and all the errors you get. Otherwise no one can help you.

Comment: Keystore is not an enviornment variable, it is a file which is in my directory.

Comment: Thanks, by putting keystore and its value in different args command executed but it is not giving any response back. It goes into wait state.

Comment: You need to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor() and capture the stream if you need the output